# Database creation with data insertion using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the error message I am getting, can you suggest any fixes?

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Quantity', table 'UOKA0209.dbo.SalesOrderLine'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I am new to this and don't have much experience working in with this language.

This is what I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO [SalesOrderLine] ([SOLID],[Quantity],[SQLStatus])
VALUES
  (1896,default,default),
  (1789,default,default),
  (3789,default,default),
  (4789,default,default),
  (5789,default,default);
```

Comment: Did you set your default values ? because you're trying to insert values with **default** but is explicitly says that your Column **Quantity** has to be "Not NULL"

Comment: Can you please confirm what database you are using: what does `SELECT @@version;` return?

Comment: dbo in table name and square brackets indicates you are using MSSQL/sql-server/T-sql not mysql. Please check and edit the tags,

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `default` if there is no default set in the database for `null` values.  So instead you can change it to be nothing --> `''` which is NOT NULL even though it's "empty" -- Or set a default for your `NOT NULL` field (Quantity) using `ALTER`

```
INSERT INTO UOKA0209.dbo.SalesOrderLine (`SOLID`, `Quantity`, `SQLStatus`) 
VALUES 
(1896,'',default),
(1789,'',default),
(3789,'',default),
(4789,'',default),
(5789,'',default);
```

Or alter your table:

```
 ALTER TABLE UOKA0209.dbo.SalesOrderLine 
     MODIFY Quantity INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

And just an *assumption* -- You'll probably have the same problem with `SQLStatus` --  So change your query to: `(4789,'',''),` OR alter that column using the same alter command above, setting it to 0 by default .. `MODIFY SQLStatus INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;`

CONVERSELY -- If you did alter your table, and set the defaults for those two columns to 0 .. That makes your query much simpler:

```
INSERT INTO UOKA0209.dbo.SalesOrderLine (`SOLID`) 
VALUES 
(1896),
(1789),
(3789),
(4789),
(5789);
```

As `Quantity` and `SQLStatus` will now default to 0 without needing input from you to do so.